# Node Js: How to send async request in batches

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios

Hope your all are doing fine.

I'm building a nodeJs script in which I want to call async requests in batches
for example, I have an array of phone numbers like this some are correct numbers and some are incorrect numbers.

```
const chunks = [["+1-321341321", "1-3213213213"], ["+1-3213321321","+1-3213413213241"]]
```

and I am passing each array of items in a POST request but the API has certain criteria it only accepts a phone number that has '+' in the start so if any batch contains a phone number that does not have '+' it will throw an error.

```
try {
 chunks.forEach(async (item) => {
   await axios.post('https://example.com/v1', { to: item.map((pn) => {
                return {
                    phone_number: pn.toString().trim()
                }
            })})
})
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

It's working correctly but If the first batch request failed due to any reason (eg: bad phone number) it's throwing an error and stops the loop. what I want to do is that if any error occurs on any batch request it should move on to the next batch.
**A failed request on the first iteration should not block the next request on the iteration.**

Comment: Can you explain the input in more detail? It looks like the inner array elements are integer expressions that evaluate to large negative numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated it. yes, they are string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
chunks.forEach((item) => {
  try {
    await axios.post('https://example.com/v1', {
      to: item.map((pn) => {
        return {
          phone_number: pn.toString().trim()
        }
      })
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})
```

Comment: How will this help?

Comment: You wrapped the entire forEach block in try catch and if it fell, then nothing happened further.
Here, when the request falls, the cycle will continue

Comment: can you explain the difference between the effect of passing try catch in or out of the loop? thank you

Comment: @ObaidAqeel If an error occurs in the loop, the entire loop will end and go to the catch section. If the error is processed inside the loop, then each iteration is processed separately and when the iteration falls, the loop does not end

Answer (score 1):

You could make the POST requests simultaneously with the help of [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

I think the following code should work:

```
Promise.all(chunks.map((item) => {
  return axios.post('https://example.com/v1', {
    to: item.map((pn) => {
      return { phone_number: pn.toString().trim() }
    })
  })
})).then((results) => {
  // ....
})
```

There is a slightly similar little example in the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example).